# Creating a long running observable from shorter observables?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a method that returns a short observable that returns 1 or 2 items, and then completes.

I would like to have an observable that continues running, and when I call a method the short observable is created and merged into the longer running observable.

Is there a way of doing this with observable operators? Or should I just use a Subject?

Comment: You could call `.Merge()` on an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` where the inner `IObservable<T>` are your short-lived observables. If you need more detail, provide some code to better explain what you want to do.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Merge won't work for me because once the shorter observables complete the longer observable will too, which I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you present the problem, there's no way around the use of subjects, specifically because you need a method call to trigger events on an existing stream.

But you can restrict the use of subjects to a minimum, which is this method call:

```
Subject<Unit> trigger;

void RefreshMethod() { trigger.OnNext(Unit.Default); }

IObservable<Item> GetLongObservable() {
    return trigger.SelectMany(_ => GetShortObservable());
}
```

Ideally, depending where the `RefreshMethod` is called from, you can try to propagate further the use of Rx and replace the subject by the actual *event* behind it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured there was no way around using a subject but just wanted to make sure. My encapsulation is exactly what you have there - a class with a `GetObservable` and a `Refresh` method.

I don't understand what you mean with that last sentence though.

Comment: The `GetShortObservable` is this - https://gist.github.com/distantcam/06e08761a3c5884949fe

Comment: What I meant is that there's probably some event which calls the refresh method (e.g. a button click ?), should this event be converted to an observable, it'd replace the subject, e.g.: `refreshButtonClickObservable.SelectUnit(),StartsWith(Unit.Default).SelectMany(_ => GetShortObservable())` but maybe not applicable in your case ?